# Javascript Arithmetical Operation inside Dynamic Table Html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm buiding a form to insert some data into a DB through a webpage.
Everything is ok, but i can't display a multiplication in a input text element of my form table.
i've checked a lot of tutorial to do this, the code should be ok but i can't have this little result.
This is my html code. The php part is ok, so i will not post it.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="./css/style2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <?php  include("form.php") ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#btnExport").click(function(e) {
            window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $('#dataTable').html());
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        </script>


        <script type=text/javascript>
        function addRow(tableID) {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var element1 = document.createElement("input");
            element1.type = "checkbox";
            element1.name="chkbox[]";
            cell1.appendChild(element1);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            cell2.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='TipoLocale[]'>";
            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            cell3.innerHTML = "<input type='text'  name='NomeLocale[]' />";
            var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
            cell3.innerHTML = "<input type='text'  name='Numero Locale[]' />";
            var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
            cell4.innerHTML =  "<input type='text'  name='TipoCarico[]' />";
            var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
            cell5.innerHTML =  "<input type='text'  name='N°[]' />";
            var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
            cell6.innerHTML =  "<input type='text'  name='Potenza[]' />";
            var cell8 = row.insertCell(7);
            cell7.innerHTML =  "<input type='text'  name='PotenzaTotale[]' />";
            var cell9 = row.insertCell(8);
            cell8.innerHTML =  "<input type='text'  name='Note[]' />";
        }

        function deleteRow(tableID) {
            try {
                var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
                var rowCount = table.rows.length;

                for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
                    var row = table.rows[i];
                    var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
                    if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                        table.deleteRow(i);
                        rowCount--;
                        i--;
                    }
               }
            } catch(e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }

    $('input').change(function(){
            var linetotals = 0;
            $('[name^="Potenza[]"').each(function(){
            n = $(this).parents('tr').find('input').eq(4).val();
                potenza = $(this).parents('tr').find('input').eq(5).val();      
                $(this).val(n*potenza/1000);
                linetotals += n*potenza/1000;
            });
            $('[name=PotenzaTotale[]]').val(linetotals);
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" id="btnExport" value=" Export Table data into Excel " />       
        <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" />
        <INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
        <form action="form.php" method="post" name="f">  
            <TABLE width="425" border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="98"></th>
                        <th width="94">TipoLocale</th>
                        <th width="121">NomeLocale</th>
                        <th width="54">NumeroLocale</th>
                        <th width="54">TipoCarico</th>
                        <th width="54">N°</th>
                        <th width="54">Potenza</th>
                        <th width="54">PotenzaTotale</th>
                        <th width="54">Note</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="dataTable">
                </tbody>
    </TABLE>
    <INPUT type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" target="_new"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

i've built [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sxR8Y/) for this

Thanks for any suggestion

Edit: Resolved.
i've added the onchange() inside che last input cell needed for the operation .

```
cell7.innerHTML =  "<input type='text'  name='Potenza[]' onchange='myfunction()';/>";
```

than added the function:

```
function myfunction(){
    var numero =  document.getElementsByName('N°[]');
    var potenza = document.getElementsByName('Potenza[]');
    var pt = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < numero.length; i++)
            {
                pt[i] = (parseInt(potenza[i].value) * parseInt(numero[i].value))/1000;
                //alert (pt[i]);
                document.getElementsByName('PotenzaTotale[]')[i].value = pt[i];
            }   
                        };
```

Works perfectly!(maybe not so clean)

updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sxR8Y/2/)

Comment: What do you mean by multiplication ? Do you mean the result or the symbol * ? If so, then use \ before * `'\*'`

Comment: yes, i mean that. i've used in the $('input').change(function(){...} without any result...

Comment: @user3241019: I don't see the OP using regexes (where `*` would need to be escaped by a backslash). In what other cases would you need it?

Comment: @Bergi Agreed. But Ashkrimn seems to need it, still donno where.

Comment: Maybe i didn't explain it well. I want to print in a input text cell the result of the multiplication between two element in the same row. a = $(this).parents('tr').find('input').eq(4).val(); b= $(this).parents('tr').find('input').eq(5).val(); c= a*b;

Comment: Can't debug this right now, did you check the two values to make sure you don't have a null ?